In complex matrices, is the adj defined by transposition or by the conjugate transpostion? And does the formula $A \text{adj}(A)=\det(A)I$ holds?
Im reading a proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem that does not specify the field on which the matrices take values. But it uses that the adjugate matrix of $A$ is $\operatorname{adj}(A)=(\operatorname{cof}(A))^T$, where $^ T$ denotes the transposition $(b_{ij})_{ij}\mapsto (b_{ji})_{ij}$. I am wondering if this is also the definition of adjugate matrix for complex matrices or if one would need to define it via $\operatorname{adj}(A)=(\operatorname{cof}(A))^*$, conjugate transposition.
Either way, is the equality $\operatorname{adj}(A)A=\det(A)I$ still true on complex matrices?

Always use mere transpose. The identity holds for matrices over any commutative ring, including $\mathbb C$, and there is no such thing as conjugate transpose for these matrices in general.
